# how to save the value which we receive from the component to the database without using apex controller

Tags: lightning-web-components

Using the child-parent relationship, am passing value to the parent and I want to save the value to the database. The parent component got value from the child without any issues and on refreshing the page, the value gets disappears as it's not saving to the database.

Parent:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Custom Object List">    
        Name:{name}<br/>
        Date:{date}<br/>
        Image:{imgInParent}   
    <c-download-Image onsavecustom={saveMethod}></c-download-Image>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire,track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELDS = [
    'Agent__c.Name',
    'Agent__c.Date__c',
    'Agent__c.Selected_Image__c'
];

export default class StudentCourseRelationship extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;   
    name;
    date;
    @track imgInParent;
    agent;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })     
    wiredRecord({error,data})
    {
        if(data)
        {
           this.agent = data;
           this.name = this.agent.fields.Name.value;
           console.log(this.name);
           this.date = this.agent.fields.Date__c.value;
           
        }
    }

    saveMethod(event)
    {
       console.log('From Parent- savemethod'); 
       this.imgInParent = event.detail;
       console.log('Child',this.imgInParent);

    }
}
```

child:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title='Download2'>      
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">            
            <template for:each={images} for:item="i">
                <li key={i.id}>      
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_3-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_1-of-12" >
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                        <img  src={i.name} data-id={i.name} onclick={openImg}>    
                    </div>
                        <h1>{i.str}</h1>                   
                        <a href={i.name} download>Download</a>
                      </div>                       
                 </li>                  
            </template>  
        </div> 
    <lightning-button label="Save"  data-id={images}  onclick={saveImg}></lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

.js

```
import Green from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Green';
import Test from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Test';
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';

export default class DownloadImage extends LightningElement {
    @api imgInParent;
    imag = Green;
    imag1 = Test;
    @track saveName;
    @track imgName;
 
    @track images = [
        {
            id :1,
            name:this.imag,
            str:this.imag.split('/')[3]
                      
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:this.imag1,
            str:this.imag1.split('/')[3]
            
        }];   
        
        
    openImg(event)
    {
        let imgId = event.target.dataset.id;
        console.log(imgId);
        this.saveName = imgId;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.images));
        
    }
    saveImg(event)
    {
        console.log('Entered Save');            
        this.imgName = this.saveName.split('/')[3];
        this.imgInParent = this.imgName;
        console.log('Image in Parent',this.imgInParent);
        const savedName = new CustomEvent("savecustom",{
            detail : this.imgInParent
        });
        console.log('Before Event',this.imgName);        
        this.dispatchEvent(savedName);
        console.log('after dispatchEvent');
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to use an apex controller?

Comment: @glls - If i remember properly I heard that without using an apex controller also we can execute this requirement, please confirm if it's not possible to execute without an apex controller and I give try with an apex

Comment: you are already using getRecord from the ui record api, you just need to read what other possibilities and methods the same api offers, here is the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_record.htm

Comment: using {createRecord} i have implemented this requirement..Thanks!